# Does it matter how big the pull up resistor is for a comparator?

Tags: comparator

Does it matter how big the pull up resistor is for a comparator?

- The datasheet of the LM339 mentions 5K1 for 5  V.
- The datasheet of the LM393 mentions 3K3 for 5 V.

For a 12 V bi polar connected comparator that would mean 7.3 mA for the 3K3 and 4.7 mA for a 5K1.

Me thinks that's quite a lot if you want to use all the 4 units of the LM339.

Can I choose 22K?

Than it would be 1.1 mA.

[image]
revision:
[image]

Comment: *Does it matter how big the pull up resistor is for a comparator?* Yes/No. It depends on your circuit (show it!). What speed you need. What else is connected to the pull up resistor. Usually values between 1 kohm and 100 kohm are OK but again: it depends on the circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, Thank you, i have added a image. the original schematic just has a opamp comparator.

Comment: Please use engineering notations.

Comment: @winny, where did i failed?

Comment: I see several pull up/down resistors, be precise which ones you're asking about. Also explain what the circuit is supposed to do. Winny means: 7.2 mA instead of: 0,007272727 A Other general hint: 7.2 mA is accurate enough. Only write 7.272727 mA if you have good reasons for that like you're measuring something that accurately. Most resistors are only 1% accurate so 7.27 mA is already much more precise than the averaye resistor.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, the one after the comparator heading to SDPT switch, currently 5K1. a classic Sample and Hold circuit for synthesizers.

Comment: Those 5.1 k ohm pull up resistors should be significantly smaller in value than R32 (1 Mohm) next to the JFET so that the 5.1 k resistors will always "win". A factor 10 should suffice so I would not make the 5.1 kohm resistors more than 100 kohm. So 22 kohm will do fine. Realize that on a PCB you can always desolder a resistor and replace it for another value. So make a prototype with 22 kohm and see how that works for you.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, just wanna keep the current in check (since I'm gonna use 4 comparators ) for a small circuit like this. since they work in opposed directions, it's only 2.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie i added a function, the original circuit use a remaining op amp from the TL074 as comparator and has no pull up or feedback of any kind.

Comment: You can make the pullup bigger to reduce current. Normally the tradeoff on bigger pullups is the slower rise time but you're not driving any load so rise time should be very quick regardless. I would get rid of all the 22pF - the cap on output serves no purpose and you don't want negative feedback in a comparator circuit, if anything you want positive feedback.

Comment: *a classic Sample and Hold circuit for synthesizers...the original circuit use a remaining op amp from the TL074* Next time: include such info in the question.

Comment: @td127 well, i learned about " hysteresis", i see some use 1mOhm resistors in the feedback and i saw another guy ( who is selling commercially ) use the 22pF capacitors. so you suggest i should delete them?

Comment: You have no specs, so you can do whatever you like but risetime and  with RC does something but where is the S&H?

Comment: I fail to see how the twin comparators derive either Track & Hold signal or Sample & hold pulses from anything.

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 I suspect the intention is for the periodic 100us pulse to generate a brief positive pulse on the top “Sample” comparator, which will turn on the FET briefly to sample the input. The bottom comparator is normally high and only briefly low so I suppose that constitutes a “Track”, although I would think it would be easier to just pull to 12V if the intent is just to keep the FET on. As for 22pF in the feedback, I’d delete them, or at least hook them to the + inputs.

Comment: TY @td127 I got it.

Comment: @td127 The upper part of the schematic as the input part is from a commercial product: "Mutable Instruments Kinks", i'm gonna remove the RC part after the jack, that was the idea some 10 hours ago, the normal operation would be the upper "comparator" and i added the lower to have the opposite operation possibility as well.  hook both 22pF feedback capacitors to the non inverted input? so i can measure once i have the pcb.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, The upper part of the schematic as the input part is from a commercial product: "Mutable Instruments Kinks", I'm gonna remove the RC part after the jack, that was the idea some 10 hours ago, the normal operation would be the upper "comparator" and i added the lower to have the opposite operation possibility as well.

Comment: @td127, uploaded a new image, but doesn't the 22pF on the second comparator feedback loop interfere with the voltage divider? i just want to prevent that comparator is going to hesitate and have erratic behavior.

Comment: @NaturalDemon  why did you remove the CR cct. used to create a one shot?  **Why are you asking a question about a partial circuit which I presume is used with an ADC with NO SPECS !**  The question is UNANSWERABLE to *Does it matter?* without how it is used specs.  As I answered you can change R and C but most likely cause metastable monotonic ADC errors if started when the input is not yet stable on the trailing edge of 1 shot.

Comment: Yes, it does (interfere with the voltage divider) but that's ok here because it just improves the hysteresis further. But I would still dispense with the feedback caps - the 339 doesn't need any hysteresis help here - your input in a sharp digital signal, right? Hysteresis is helpful for slow-moving inputs but that's not the case here.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, it's used for a DIY synthesizer sample and hold module, the "gates" can come from a function generator like "Make Noise Maths", LFO's, Arturia Keystep keyboard, other eurorack synthsizer modules, don't want one shot, i wanna hold it it. for some amount of times. no digital equipment here.

Check on Make Noise Maths ... a very cool thing.

Comment: @td127, it's a DIY eurorack Synthesizer Sample and Hold module, it's either a square wave from a LFO, he stroke from a finger on the keyboard or something similar.

Comment: now i have 3 answers, but i can only choose one.

Comment: How can you decide what to do when you haven't defined what it is supposed to do.   Make Noise Math is just a reincarnated Moog Synth.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, pretty good, it's a actually a SERGE schematic, most of the Stuff Make Noise makes is Buchla based and a few thing are Moog based. but Tony Rolando did work at Moog assembling the Moog phatty or something.
Witch i think is a bit unfair if you ask me. because i "assume" the RC thing is sort of a trigger circuit aka RC Differentiator? using an online calculator it shows 100pF and 110K Ohm  = 110 µSek or am i wrong?

Comment: wrong ... 100 e-12 * 0.110 e6 = 11e-6  or 11 us  but since threshold is not 63% it works out to a 10us one shot on the clock rising edge.

Comment: Thanks for the Buchla reference.  he was 15 yrs before my time.  From his site background https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q4cE.jpg

Comment: Masterful layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqGxC.jpg  Are you trying to duplicate this build?  which one? https://www.google.com/search?q=don+buchla+schematics&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvKJ7o14w3RvGsoY0kyGiIg9zQeOWg:1634923206863&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgi-vHw97zAhWdk2oFHcgFAB8Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1760&bih=867&dpr=1.09

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130769/discussion-between-naturaldemon-and-tony-stewart-ee75).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, i have opened a chat and i have placed a 2 x 2 header around the 100K and capacitor, so i can bypass it it (computer) jumpers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have correctly surmised, the current through that pull-up resistor is effectively wasted power in the resistor, and you are right to raise this question.

The answer is mostly about what the comparator output is connected to. One consideration is output transistion speed, which will depend on the capacitance (or inductance) that the output is driving. For example, perhaps the comparator is driving a MOSFET gate, which has inherent capacitance modelled on the right here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTFECS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The internal open-collector transistor of the comparator is able to pull its output down to 0V very quickly, but for the output to transition from low to high state, you are relying on R to source all current needed to charge C. Obviously, the lower R is, the more quickly the output can slew to a high voltage. In this scenario, if switching speed is of little concern, you can make R very high (see below for an upper limit), wasting less power.

Another factor to consider is resitive loading of the output. You must treat the pull-up resistor as you would in any situation where it forms part of a larger system of impedances. For instance, to implement input hysteresis (to form a schmitt trigger), you need to provide positive feedback from output to input, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9pWd7.png)</sup>

I used R1 and R2 to derive a switching "threshold" potential of about half of \$V_{CC}\$ at node X. Resistor R4 is allowing this threshold to be slightly modulated by the comparator output. This is no problem when the comparator output is low, because the output transistor can sink a lot of current, and drag the output all the way to 0V, but when the output is high, R3 forms a potential divider with R4, between \$V_{CC}\$ and whatever potential point X settles at. This means that the output voltage will always be less than the full \$V_{CC}\$.

The amount by which the output falls short of the full power supply potential might be problematic in some instances. In this example, the output is supposed to switch off the P-channel MOSFET when high. That output might not be quite high enough to do the job!

So the question now is "what range of values can I use for a pull-up resistor at the output of an LM393?"

The lower limit is defined by the maximum collector current that the comparator's output transistor is able to sink, which comes directly from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf?ts=1634778958091). On page 6 we have this information:

[image]

As you can see under "Output Sink Current", maximum collector current is typically 16mA, but if you are really unlucky that could be as low as 6mA. For a bullet-proof design, you should aim for a resistance that will pass *at most* 6mA when the output is low. For a power supply of 12V, that resistance would be *at least*:

$$ R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{12V}{6mA} = 2k\Omega $$

The entry "Output Leakage Current" tells you that when the output is high, at +5V, the transistor can still pass 0.1nA of current. That's negligible in most cases. If you want to drop less than 100mV across the pull-up resistor, then use Ohm's law to find the maximum permissible resistance:

$$ R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{0.1V}{0.1nA} = 1G\Omega $$

Clearly that is impractically large, and you'll never use a resistor any where near that. However, the situation worsens as the output voltage increases. On page 7 of the datasheet there's an entry for "Output Leakage Current" when the output is +30V:

[image]

That current is 1μA. To keep the voltage drop across the pull-up resistor under 100mV, you use *at most* this resistance:

$$ R = \frac{0.1V}{1\mu A} = 100k\Omega $$

The only other thing I can think of to mention, is that higher resistances are more noisy (probably not a concern for digitial comparator outputs), and more susceptible to interference due to inductive, capacitive or electromagnetic pickup. That's too big a topic for this answer, but the usual approach is to prefer smaller resistances over large.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it's a 12 Volt bipolar power supply, so there is a range of 24 Volts, calculation shows 4K, so a 4K99 or 5K1 should do the job, i just don't want this simple module to consume alot of power. i have chosen for a capacitor in the feedback to prevent hesitation at the tripping point.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on three things:

1. How much capacitance in output of comparator or connected to output.
2. How fast you want the voltage to rise.
3. How much current you can waste in resistor.
   If you want to save some power while have best performance you can use current source instead of resistor

Answer (score 2):

This works for low sampling rates like 10 ~50 kHz and the input differentiator is 10 us on the rising edge. The **T=RC=(100k+10k)*100pF= 11 us** but the one shot duration depends on the   comparator threshold of 10k/110k * 12V and the signal returning from 5V-0.7V towards -0.7V

The negative feedback cap is bad news and just forms a relaxation oscillator of current ramps during the comparator off time.

The Comparator pullup R and C forms a time constant for delayed turn off delay to hold by adding RC= 5k1*100pF= 0.51 us of one shot duration to the 16 us so has no benefit there other than to suppress oscillations from the interference possible from the NFB cap that must to be removed.

> Does it matter how big the pull up resistor is for a comparator?

Yes but it is not that critical so there is room for variation as required.

The S&H state is the fast for sample ON active with the active low state of the comparator.  This one shot duration has low delay to begin sample and slower shutoff from the RC time constant of the pullup R.

If 5k1*100pF= ~ 0.5 us additional sample time is acceptable then you could consider **50k pullup**, if the circuit trace and input capacitance was only **10pF.** and remove both 100 pF caps.

Although if the 12V logic threshold was Vcc/2 rather than 63% of Vcc the turn off delay is only 0.5/0.63 of RC=T, so the FET gate threshold voltage will affect this trailing edge delay of the negative one shot output for sample depends on your ADC sampling rate and method of triggering Start conversion which must occur after the FET S&H has settled.